# php is_dir function weird behavior

Tags: php, python, linux

I was running a php code in a linux server. I noticed that my php code is getting failed at a point where I am using `is_dir()` function. The `is_dir()` function is returning `false` even when the directory is present in the server. Permission, ownership looks fine. I became little suspicious with this and tried same approach using python using equivalent functions in python language(both php and python codes are show below). python code works fine and giving me result as expected.

On further debugging, I noticed that sub-directories created within its parent directory has some weird behavior. The inode values of those directories are messed up.

```
386999     drwxrwsr-x 2 guiuser guiuser    6 Oct 24 03:04 temp

4451771015 drwxrwsr-x 2 guiuser guiuser    6 Oct 24 03:08 temp_1
```

When I run the php code, `is_dir()` function returns `true` for `temp` and `false` for `temp_1`. But python code returns `true` for both. Weird right?

For some reason `is_dir()` function fails when inode value is a large number.

Note: I am using php5. No dependency on apache or other webserver. I am running it as an executable. Also both `temp` and `temp_1` are created in a directory on a mount point which is of type `xfs`.

*PHP code:*

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  class test
  {
   public function __construct()
   {
   }
   public function check()
   {    
      $DirM = "/path/to/folder";    
      if (!is_dir ($DirM))
      {
    print $DirM . " Not a directory\n";
        return;
      }
      print $DirM . " is a directory\n";
   }
  }    
  $test1 = new test();
  $test1->check(); 
?>
```

*Python code:*

```
import os
print(os.path.isdir("/path/to/folder"))
```

Please help me in understanding this issue.

Comment: try ```!is_dir($DirM)``` no space

Comment: [This](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php#98338) relates to CIFS file systems, may be something similar for mounting XFS filesystems on 32 bit systems.

Comment: @Nigel Ren, my system is 64 bit and also i would like to confirm whether, is_dir function has this issue with large inode values or did I miss something in my analysis? I have seen this article before and may be it has biased me into this conclusion.